# Violin plot shows distribution at each value of the variable separately

Tags: r, violin-plot

I’m trying to create a violin plot, separately for two groups, on a variable ranging from 1 to 5 using the following code:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(var_group, var_y))
p + geom_violin()
```

What I get is this:

[image: violin plot]

To me, the plot looks as if the data are not plotted correctly, or the variable is not recognized as a continuous variable.

I made sure the variable of interest is numeric:

```
df$var_y <- as.numeric(as.character(df$var_y))
```

But nothing changed.

How to create a violin plot where the distribution of the entire variable is easier to see?

I would like to make sure the distribution is depicted correctly.

EDIT 2:
Another violin plot I created in exactly the same way using data on a different variable (ranging 1 to 10, have been a numerical variable from the very beginning as far as I know) looks completely different, which makes me wonder about the one described at the beginning:
[2nd violin plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp43M.jpg)

EDIT:

I use a dataset in long format with 70 occasions per id. For data protection, in the following I include only data on three variables - id, var_group, var_y - from two different ids (1,2) with group names labeled as A and B. The entire dataset includes approx. 4,200 rows.

```r
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2), var_group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B"), var_y = c(3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, NA, 4, 5, 
5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, 3, NA, 4, 5, 4, 
NA, NA, 4, 5, 5, 3, NA, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 1, 1, NA, NA, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(211L, 212L, 
213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 
224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 
235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 
246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 
257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 
268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 
279L, 280L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 
430L, 431L, 432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 
441L, 442L, 443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 
452L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 
463L, 464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 
474L, 475L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 
485L, 486L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 490L))
```

Comment: From the help file `?geom_violin()`: "a violin plot is a mirrored density plot displayed in the same way as a boxplot." So if you split the violin in half and laid it down it probably will represent the shape you think you should be seeing. Does that make sense? I think that the code is functioning as it should buy you have a vision in your mind that is something different, maybe a density plot where the distribution is shown horizontally?

Comment: The problem is that a violin plot is a poor representation of your data. In the example data set, your y axis variable `y_var` exclusively has integer values. A violin plot shows the estimated density throughout the entire continuous range, for which your data should really be continuous too. Although you say your data are continuous, they aren't really - they take only 5 equally spaced values. A violin plot will always look "lumpy" in this scenario, and the amount of lumpiness is arbitrary - you can reduce the lumpiness if you set `geom_violin(adjust = 2)` or play with this number.

Comment: Your `var_y` is integer data across only 5 integers, so this looks as expected. I would not recommend a violin plot to visualize these data.

Comment: But I would advise you rethink how you present your data.

Comment: Given the issues that jpsmith and others have pointed out, this question might be a better fit for CrossValidated.

Comment: Thank you! These are very useful comments. I was wondering why the distribution for group B reminds the normal distribution but hasn't been depicted like one.

Comment: @Karolina this is because the bandwidth of the density kernel is narrow compared to the space between your integer values. If you set `adjust = 3` (or maybe a higher number), it _will_ look like a normal distribution.